# how to write the cursor's data in a txt file? visual fox pro

Tags: foxpro, fgets, visual-foxpro, fputs

well i have a cursor for example

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, colN from cursor into into array thecursor
```

my current cursor is the cursor

i have got all its data information including null, null information

how can i a txt as it:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, colN 
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5
a1,b1,,d1,e1
11,12,13,14,
,bb,cc,dd,ee
```

so you could see at rows
`a1,b1,,d1,e1` i have a null value between b1 and d1
so you could see i have a null value at row

```
`11,12,13,14,`(here null value)
```

and i have a null value at last row

```
(here null value), cc,dd,ee
```

so i want this finally txt file

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, colN 
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5
a1,b1,,d1,e1
11,12,13,14,
,bb,cc,dd,ee


**I need this was dynamic i refer it receive a cursor and do it with any cursor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly move the data into a text file instead of cursor as below:

`select col1, col2, col3, col4, colN from table to file test.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the COPY TO command? Try:

```
COPY TO <filename> TYPE DELIMITED WITH ""
```

Comment: You need to insert the filename between COPY TO and TYPE DELIMITED.  Tamar tried to put <filename> there, but markdown ate it.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't even think of that.